# Add Data in multiple classes Realm swift

Tags: swift, realm, swift4

I'm new to swift. I'm working with realm in swift. I've a realm database which have following classes.

[image: Example]

I'm inserting same data in each class from application as:

```
for item in myarray {
         print(item)

   let realm = try! Realm(fileURL: db_path!)
   try! realm.write({
       let obj = English()
       obj.rowid = ((item["rowid"] as? NSString)?.integerValue)!
       obj.words = (item["word"] as? NSString)! as String
       obj.frequency = ((item["frequency"] as? NSString)?.integerValue)!
       realm.add(obj)
       print("successfully added to database")
   })

 }
```

```
class English : Object {

    @objc dynamic var rowid = 0
    @objc dynamic var words = ""
    @objc dynamic var frequency = 0  

}
```

This is saving data in English class. Now I want to save same object in other realm class like Arabic, languages, test.

Should I've to make separate object type class for each class?

Comment: You cannot save a class A objects into class B table. Classes are stored in their respective class types. *Should I've to make separate object type class for each class?* - yes, that's how Realm works. You can leverage subclassing but the use case here is unclear so I don't know if that would work. Can you explain what you're attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

No ,you can create object of each class and assign English class object to other like this

```
let obj1 = Arabic()
obj1 = obj//English Class Object
```

And append like this

```
realm.add(obj1)
```

Comment: can we add data in all tables(classes) of realm by using just 1 object type class

Comment: According to me No its not possible.

Comment: Can you clarify this answer as you cannot assign objects in that fashion. It would be like stating `let a: String = "Hello"` and then `let b: Int = 1` and then your statement `a = b`.